# How to set height of a bootstrap's row?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have such a HTML:

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <form>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="vipResult">Result</label>
        <textarea class="form-control result" id="vipResult"></textarea>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

And it is displayed like this:

[image: result]

Now I want to change the height of the textarea. I tried to set `height: 200%` for it,but it doesn't work.Maybe I should change the height of the row,how can I do that?

Comment: Post your code here rather than Image.

Comment: provide your css code aswell.

Comment: This seems to have nothing to do with the Bootstrap row. It's a matter of setting textarea height.

Answer (score 0):

//to change the height of row use

```
textarea{height:200px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple textarea element in your code use separate ID for each them to style them separately.
or you can use it like this

```
<textarea style= "height:200px;"></textarea>
```

this is another way of styling an html element.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

```css
#textareaheight{
      height:200px;
     }
```

```html
<form>
      <textarea type="text"  name="text" class="form-control" id="textareaheight"></textarea>
     </form>
```

You can try this code for height.

Here you can use `height:200px` with id tag

```
<head>
<style>
    #textareaheight{
        height:200px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<br><br><br>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
    <form>
        <textarea type="text"  name="text" class="form-control" id="textareaheight"></textarea>
    </form>
    </div>
```